# Symfony 2 form bind custom fields

Tags: forms, object, symfony, entity, bind

I have some questions related to symfony 2 form component,

Lets say I have an entity which has a field "created_by" which refers to the user who created that entity. When a new record is created I want to set that field with the logged in user in my app.
I can do this is controller ($entity->setCreatedBy($user), but I would prefer to include this login inside the form class itself.
I can pass the user object, to the form in constructor/setter method but then how would I "bind" it to the entity? 
Do I need to create a field in the form? I could make an hidden field but I prefer not showing the user id that way.

Is there any equivalent to updateObject or doSave methods from symfony 1.4?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You could use a listener and the prePersist event as show here http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Comment: You are right: +1! Moreover I don't understand why he want to include user data into a form. I'm not quite sure that this is a safe way. Surely is a waste of bits to be transferred from server to client and vice versa.